# How to bind an object to an event so that when touch the event is called in SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, skiasharp

I draw a pie chart using SkiaSharp, I want some information to be displayed when I clicked on the pieces of these charts

[image]

There is such a thing, for example, when you click on the black color, some information was displayed

Answer (score 0):

**You could use the `CanvasView` to draw the circle. And use `SKCanvas.DrawPath` to draw four parts of the circle with four colors.**

Xaml:  `TouchCanvasView` is the custom control according to the `CanvasView`.

```
<Grid>
        <local:TouchCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" PaintSurface="OnPainting" Touched="OnTouched" />
    </Grid>
```

Define the variables:

```
      private SKPoint sKPoint;
    public float _temp;
    public float _total;
    public float _percentage;
    public float _arcAnglePoint;
    private bool isDraw = false;
    SKPath black; 
    private bool isblack = false;
    SKPath orange; 
    private bool isOrange = false;
    SKPath red; 
    private bool isred = false;
    SKPath green; 
    private bool isgreen = false;

    private ObservableCollection<Profile> _profileDetails;
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> ProfileDetails
    {
        get { return _profileDetails; }
        set
        {
            _profileDetails = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProfileDetails));
        }
    }

    private float _sweepAngle = 0;
    public float SweepAngle
    {
        get { return _sweepAngle; }
        set
        {
            _sweepAngle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SweepAngle));
        }
    }

    private float _startAngle = 0;
    public float StartAngle
    {
        get { return _startAngle; }
        set
        {
            _startAngle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SweepAngle));
        }
    }
```

**Use the two method below to get the percentage of the circle of four colors.**

```
        private void ArcPercentCalculator(float _percentage)
    {
        var _sweepAngle = _percentage / 100 * 360;
        _arcAnglePoint = _sweepAngle;
        _arcAnglePoint = _arcAnglePoint * -1;
    }

    private void PercentageCalculator(float values)
    {
        var percent = values / _total * 100;
        _percentage = percent;

    }
```

OnPainting:  Use the `PaintSurface` to draw the circle and text. The //black, //orange, //read, //green mean the different execution for different colors.

```
private void OnPainting(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {

        SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear();

        SKPoint center = new SKPoint(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2);
        SKRect _rect = new SKRect(center.X - 150, center.Y - 150, center.X + 150, center.Y + 150);

        ProfileDetails = new ObservableCollection<Profile>()
        {
            new Profile{Id = 0,Name = "Blank", sKColors = SKColors.Black , Values = 541 },
            new Profile{Id = 1,Name = "Orange",sKColors = SKColors.Orange ,Values = 1587 },
            new Profile{Id = 2,Name = "Red",sKColors = SKColors.Red, Values = 965 },
            new Profile{Id = 3,Name = "Green",sKColors = SKColors.Green, Values = 857 }
        };

        foreach (var item in ProfileDetails)
        {
            _total += item.Values;
        }

        //black
        #region
        PercentageCalculator(ProfileDetails[0].Values);
        ArcPercentCalculator(_percentage);

        SweepAngle = _arcAnglePoint;
        SweepAngle = (float)Math.Round(SweepAngle, 2);

        if (ProfileDetails[0].Id == 0)
        {
            StartAngle = (float)0;
            _temp = SweepAngle;
        }
        else
        {
            StartAngle = (float)_temp - 1;
            var x = SweepAngle;
            _temp = _temp + x;
        }

        using (SKPath path = new SKPath())
        using (SKPaint fillPaint = new SKPaint())
        {
            fillPaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
            fillPaint.StrokeWidth = 50;
            fillPaint.Color = ProfileDetails[0].sKColors;
            path.AddArc(_rect, StartAngle, SweepAngle);
            black = fillPaint.GetFillPath(path);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, fillPaint);
        }
        #endregion

        //Orange
        #region
        PercentageCalculator(ProfileDetails[1].Values);
        ArcPercentCalculator(_percentage);

        SweepAngle = _arcAnglePoint;
        SweepAngle = (float)Math.Round(SweepAngle, 2);

        if (ProfileDetails[1].Id == 0)
        {
            StartAngle = (float)0;
            _temp = SweepAngle;
        }
        else
        {
            StartAngle = (float)_temp - 1;
            var x = SweepAngle;
            _temp = _temp + x;
        }

        using (SKPath path = new SKPath())
        using (SKPaint fillPaint = new SKPaint())
        {
            fillPaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
            fillPaint.StrokeWidth = 50;
            fillPaint.Color = ProfileDetails[1].sKColors;
            path.AddArc(_rect, StartAngle, SweepAngle);
            orange = fillPaint.GetFillPath(path);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, fillPaint);
        }
        #endregion

        //red
        #region
        PercentageCalculator(ProfileDetails[2].Values);
        ArcPercentCalculator(_percentage);

        SweepAngle = _arcAnglePoint;
        SweepAngle = (float)Math.Round(SweepAngle, 2);

        if (ProfileDetails[2].Id == 0)
        {
            StartAngle = (float)0;
            _temp = SweepAngle;
        }
        else
        {
            StartAngle = (float)_temp - 1;
            var x = SweepAngle;
            _temp = _temp + x;
        }

        using (SKPath path = new SKPath())
        using (SKPaint fillPaint = new SKPaint())
        using (SKPaint outlinePaint = new SKPaint())
        {
            fillPaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
            fillPaint.StrokeWidth = 50;
            fillPaint.Color = ProfileDetails[2].sKColors; //_Color

            path.AddArc(_rect, StartAngle, SweepAngle);
            red = fillPaint.GetFillPath(path);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, fillPaint);
        }
        #endregion

        //green
        #region
        PercentageCalculator(ProfileDetails[3].Values);
        ArcPercentCalculator(_percentage);

        SweepAngle = _arcAnglePoint;
        SweepAngle = (float)Math.Round(SweepAngle, 2);

        if (ProfileDetails[3].Id == 0)
        {
            StartAngle = (float)0;
            _temp = SweepAngle;
        }
        else
        {
            StartAngle = (float)_temp - 1;
            var x = SweepAngle;
            _temp = _temp + x;
        }

        using (SKPath path = new SKPath())
        using (SKPaint fillPaint = new SKPaint())
        using (SKPaint outlinePaint = new SKPaint())
        {
            fillPaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
            fillPaint.StrokeWidth = 50;
            fillPaint.Color = ProfileDetails[3].sKColors; //_Color

            path.AddArc(_rect, StartAngle, SweepAngle);
            green = fillPaint.GetFillPath(path);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, fillPaint);
        }
        #endregion

        //draw text
        if (isDraw)
        {
            SKPaint paint = new SKPaint();
            paint.TextSize = 28;
            paint.Color = SKColors.Purple;
            paint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial", SKFontStyleWeight.Bold, SKFontStyleWidth.Normal, SKFontStyleSlant.Italic);

            if (isblack)
            {                
                canvas.DrawText(ProfileDetails[0].Name, sKPoint, paint);
            }
            else if (isOrange)
            {
                canvas.DrawText(ProfileDetails[1].Name, sKPoint, paint);
            }
            else if (isred)
            {
                canvas.DrawText(ProfileDetails[2].Name, sKPoint, paint);
            }
            else if (isgreen)
            {
                canvas.DrawText(ProfileDetails[3].Name, sKPoint, paint);
            }
        }
        _total = 0;
    }
```

**Use the custom renderer to get the point (x,y) which you clicked from `Touched` event. And then use the SKPath.Contains(float x, float y)` to determine whether the point is in the specified area.**

TouchCanvasView:

```
public class TouchCanvasView : SKCanvasView, ITouchCanvasViewController
{
    public event Action<SKPoint> Touched;

    public virtual void OnTouch(SKPoint point)
    {
        var x = point.X;
        var y = point.Y;
        Console.WriteLine("x1 = {0}----------------y1={1}", x, y);
        Touched?.Invoke(point);
    }
}

public interface ITouchCanvasViewController : IViewController
{
    void OnTouch(SKPoint point);
}
```

TouchCanvasViewRenderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TouchCanvasView), typeof(TouchCanvasViewRenderer))]
namespace App10.Droid
{
public class TouchCanvasViewRenderer : SKCanvasViewRenderer
{
    public TouchCanvasViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SKCanvasView> e)
    {
        // clean up old native control
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Touch -= OnTouch;
        }

        // do clean up old element
        if (Element != null)
        {
            var oldTouchCanvas = (TouchCanvasView)Element;
            var oldTouchController = (ITouchCanvasViewController)Element;

            // ...
        }

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // set up new native control
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Touch += OnTouch;
        }

        // set up new element
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var newTouchCanvas = (TouchCanvasView)Element;
            var newTouchController = (ITouchCanvasViewController)Element;

            // ...
        }
    }

    private void OnTouch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {

        var touchController = Element as ITouchCanvasViewController;


        if (touchController != null)
        {
            var wasTap = e.Event.ActionMasked == MotionEventActions.Up || e.Event.ActionMasked == MotionEventActions.Cancel;
            if (wasTap)
            {
                //var scale = Control.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
                //touchController.OnTouch(new SKPoint(e.Event.GetX() / scale, e.Event.GetY() / scale));
                touchController.OnTouch(new SKPoint(e.Event.GetX(), e.Event.GetY()));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**OnTouched event of this `TouchCanvasView` to get the point (x,y) and do the judement.**

```
 private void OnTouched(SKPoint obj)
    {
        float x = obj.X;
        float y = obj.Y;

        if (black.Contains(x, y))
        {
            sKPoint = obj;
            isDraw = true;
            isblack = true;
            isOrange = false;
            isred = false;
            isgreen = false;
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
        else if (orange.Contains(x, y))
        {
            sKPoint = obj;
            isDraw = true;
            isblack = false;
            isOrange = true;
            isred = false;
            isgreen = false;
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
        else if (red.Contains(x, y))
        {
            sKPoint = obj;
            isDraw = true;
            isblack = false;
            isOrange = false;
            isred = true;
            isgreen = false;
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
        else if (green.Contains(x, y))
        {
            sKPoint = obj;
            isDraw = true;
            isblack = false;
            isOrange = false;
            isred = false;
            isgreen = true;
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
        else
        {
            isDraw = false;
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
 public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Values { get; set; }
    public SKColor sKColors { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated my reply with the whold code.

Comment: Inside text not added for me

Comment: Have you add all the code stpe bu step? The code should work.